# есть ли отличие php-curl от системной утилиты curl?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

У меня на убунту развернут LAMP.

при иcпользовании curl в php получил ошибку, что расширения такого нет.
проверил, системной утилиты curl также не оказалось. 
Установил php-curl, curl - в php заработал, а системной утилиты все еще нет (как и ожидалось).

Вопрос, является ли системная утилита curl глобальной? Т.е. можно ли только ее ставить, и не ставить php-curl?

Т.е. мне curl нужен как в php так и отдельно в терминале. Можно ли одним пакетом curl или curl-php обойтись?

Comment: Это разные вещи.

Answer (score 2):

программа *curl* — это пользовательский интерфейс командной строки к библиотеке *libcurl*.

библиотека *php-curl* — это программный интерфейс для интерпретатора *php* к той же самой библиотеке *libcurl*.

интерфейсы эти совершенно разные. ни о какой их «взаимозаменяемости», конечно, и речи быть не может.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже думал, что программа `curl` и `php-curl` эксплуатируют одну либу, по сути являясь интерфейсом для командной строки и для языка PHP. Начал разбираться, у меня Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, поэтому менеджер пакетов `apt`.

Смотрим зависимости пакета `curl`: `apt-cache depends curl`:

```
curl
  Зависит: libc6
  Зависит: libcurl3-gnutls
  Зависит: zlib1g
```

Получается, ядро - библиотека `libcurl3-gnutls`.

Теперь посмотрим зависимости пакета `php-curl`: `apt-cache depends php-curl`:

```
php-curl
  Зависит: php-common
  Зависит: php7.0-curl
```

Пакеты могут быть "сборками" других пакетов. Смотрим зависимости пакета `php7.0-curl`: `apt-cache depends php7.0-curl`:

```
php7.0-curl
  Зависит: php-common
  Зависит: ucf
  Зависит: php7.0-common
  Зависит: libc6
  Зависит: libcurl3
```

Таким образом, тут используется либа `libcurl3`, которая не одно и тоже, что `libcurl3-gnutls`.

На другой системе (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) `libcurl4` и `libcurl3` соответственно.

На Debian 8 - совпало: `libcurl3`.

Те же самые манипуляции можно сделать через `apt-rdepends`, которая строит сразу весь граф зависимостей, но ее нужно поставить. Тогда то же самое можно сделать еще проще:

```
apt-rdepends -d php-curl | grep libcurl
apt-rdepends -d curl | grep libcurl
```

Выводы:

- пакеты разные
- основная либа у программы curl и curl из PHP может совпадать, либо быть разной, в зависимости от "свежести" пакетов PHP и курла
- поэтому между "курлом" из консоли и PHP-ным курлом связь есть, но ставятся они отдельно друг от друга и могут использовать различные версии одной библиотеки